# Create PDF from different ranges in multiple Excel sheets with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I need to export several Excel sheets into one PDF file. I am currently using the following:

```
Sub CreatePDF()

    Sheets("ReportPage1").Select
    Range("Print_Area").Select
    Sheets("ReportPage2").Select
    Range("Print_Area").Select
    Sheets("ReportPage3").Select
    Range("Print_Area").Select

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("ReportPage1", "ReportPage2", "ReportPage3")).Select
        Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:="C:\temp\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("ReportPage1").Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

The problem is that all print areas are different. The PDF that is generated is using the range address of print area from ReportPage1 for all the pages.

I tried in Excel itself, outside of VBA, and when I have selected, for example, ReportPage1!A1:E30 and ReportPage2!A1:F70, when I select both sheets it will change the selected ranges to ReportPage1!A1:E30 and ReportPage2!A1:E30.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of doing Selection.exportasfixedformat. Could you not change that to application.exportasfixedFormat and then use the To and From to select the pages you need?

Comment: Or workbook.exportasfixedformat...

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these would work I believe. Remember, I need to select specific areas from each sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. If I don't select any ranges on the specific pages it will automatically get the Print_Area range of each sheet.

```
Sub CreatePDF()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("ReportPage1", "ReportPage2", "ReportPage3")).Select

    Sheets("ReportPage1").Activate

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:="C:\temp\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("ReportPage1").Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this issue was haunting me for couple of weeks.