# VBA - 1 page setup different than rest (unknown #) pages

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do page setup on multiple sheets with same range. However, one of the sheets "Dashboard" has different page set up range. It is going to be "D24:K73" How can I accomplish that with the code below? I have tried modifying it but my skills do not produce wanted results.

```
 Sub Octsaveaspdf()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim FilePath As String
   For Each ws In Sheets
     If ws.Visible Then ws.Select (False)
   Next

   FilePath = Range("Instructions!B16").Value
   FileName = Range("Dashboard!Q26").Text
     Range("$p24:$w73").Select
     Application.PrintCommunication = False
     With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
    .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With

  Application.PrintCommunication = True
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FilePath & "Compare " & FileName & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I truly appreciate all the help :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Move your export into a separate procedure and call it multiple times with different ranges to export.

The code below will work through each visible sheet and export different ranges depending on the sheet name.
Each export will be given the same name, so you'll need to do something about that to stop problems with file name conflicts.

```
Private FilePath As String
Private FileName As String

Public Sub OctSaveAsPDF()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B16")
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Q26")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible Then
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "Dashboard"
                    PerformExport ws.Range("D24:K73")
                Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                    PerformExport ws.Range("A1:Z10")
                Case Else
                    PerformExport ws.Range("P24:W73")
            End Select
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

Public Sub PerformExport(xpRng As Range)
    With xpRng
        With .Parent.PageSetup 'The parent of the range is the worksheet.
            .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
            .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
        End With

        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
              Type:=xlTypePDF _
            , FileName:=FilePath & "Compare " & FileName & ".pdf" _
            , Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
            , IncludeDocProperties:=True _
            , IgnorePrintAreas:=False _
            , OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this but I don't always have same sheet names. Dashboard is the only sheet that is constant.. rest change. Thank you Darren

Comment: It will still work - `Case "Dashboard"` will fire for the dashboard and `Case Else` will fire for all other sheets (you can remove the `Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"` and the following indented line - that was just an example).

Comment: Darren, I tried your code. I do need all sheets to print on one pdf. There are about 10-15 sheets that go to same people. I was able to remove case sheet1 etc and yes that works.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure.  I tried the solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948414/create-pdf-from-different-ranges-in-multiple-excel-sheets-with-vba but it wouldn't accept a string variable as a string of sheet names - only hard-coded sheet names.

Comment: Yes that won't work. I went the other route. I used vba to hide all the cells that are not in my range. and then i printed pdf. Worked well. I really appreciate your time and help. It is amazing to get help. Have an awesome day!

Comment: True, this internet thing is amazing.  Much easier than the banging head on wall method I started on. :)